# "Using" vs [DllImport]?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, using

I was wondering what is the very top most declared references and why we still need to use DllImport? I'm talking C#.

Comment: Been meaning to make this blog for a while: http://tergiver.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/understanding-the-using-directive/

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36920388/1710577

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [MDSN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The DllImport attribute is very useful when reusing existing unmanaged code in a managed application. For instance, your managed application might need to make calls to the unmanaged WIN32 API.

Basically, when you're writing a .NET application, and a library does not have a managed wrapper (it's written in unmanaged code), you need to use DllImport to interoperate with it. Otherwise, you can reference managed libraries with a `using` statement like you normally would any base class library.

Answer (score 5):

It's used when you need to call unmanaged code.

For example, you might need to make a call to a windows API function, so you could do declare something like this:

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="GetUserName", ExactSpelling=false,
SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool GetUserName(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] lpBuffer,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Int32[] nSize );
```

references:
http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/01/call-unmanaged-code-part-1-simple-dllimport/

Answer (score 3):

The `using` directive includes a namespace from a referenced managed assembly.
The `DllImport` is used to import methods from **unmanaged** DLLs.

Answer (score 3):

DLLImport is used to import a native dll library into a managed(.net) application. For example a library written in C++ can be imported and used in your c# project.

Using is used to reference a namespace located in one of the managed referenced dlls.  These are normally .net assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

DllImport is for importing a function that is contained in a DLL that is not managed by .NET. The using statements are for allowing your code to easily reference other .NET assemblies without using the fully qualified name.

Comment: Using does not import anything, the executable does not become bigger, simply the source code file has visibility on something declared in any of the referenced assemblies.

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. I revised it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio creates for you the basic references (System for example).

You don't need DllImport unless you want to make use of native libraries