# Calling mangled non-managed C++ DLL function in C#

Tags: c#, c++14, stdcall

For some reasons, I have to create a C++ DLL file containing functions with __stdcall calling convention.

```
namespace NS
{
    __declspec(dllexport) std::string __stdcall Function(int Num);
}
```

To be able to use it in C#, I did this way:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "?Function@NS@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z"]
static extern String Function(int Num);
```

The EntryPoint string was obtained with DUMPBIN. When I run the application, I get the error `Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'mydll.dll'.`

Both C++ and C# applications were constructed with Visual Studio 2020 in x64 Debug mode.

Can someone suggest how to fix the problem?

Note-> I did not use `extern "C"` to be able to use `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: You cannot just pass a `std::string` (or `std::vector`) from native c++ to c#. You need to marshal them. And as far as I know pInvoke only supports "old style" c functions.

Comment: You also can't call a mangled name like that, you would need to do some messing around with `GetProcAddress`. If you would have used `extern C` and a normal `LPWSTR` buffered parameter it would be far easier.